# Monitor what is being sent to /dev/null?

Tags: monitoring, devices, open-files

Just for fun:
Is there a way to monitor/capture/dump whatever is being written to `/dev/null`?

On Debian, or FreeBSD, if it matters, any other OS specific solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Possible, but as the answers and comments describe it's /very/ much not a good idea.

Comment: @Shadur: There might be bad solutions but that doesn't make the idea uninteresting or a bad idea.

Comment: Indeed, I just found this question because I was considering what an analysis of the content from many captured `/dev/null`s might turn up. I wouldn't want to do the research myself, but I'd love to read the results. (There would very likely be some ethical issues in "looking through people's trash" essentially, but the concept is interesting nonetheless.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Making `/dev/null` a named pipe is probably the easiest way. Be warned that some programs (`sshd`, for example) will act abnormally or fail to execute when they find out that it isn't a special file (or they may read from `/dev/null`, expecting it to return `EOF`).

```
# Remove special file, create FIFO and read from it
rm /dev/null && mkfifo -m622 /dev/null && tail -f /dev/null
# Remove FIFO, recreate special file
rm /dev/null && mknod -m666 /dev/null c 1 3
```

This should work under all Linux distributions, and all major BSDs.

Comment: One thing to note is that if the `tail` fails, then a lot of programs may fail because the pipe's buffer is full.

Comment: Programs that read from `/dev/null` aren't going to like this.

Comment: @Gilles - Indeed, hence my note.

Comment: Just like that I can recreate `/dev/null` ?! there is no magic about it?

Comment: @Ali Yes. `No magic` is a guiding principle in the UNIX philosophy.

Comment: Ahem `/dev/null` *is* magic, `mknod /dev/null c 1 3` is the magic formula to invoke it. (And you need super-powers for that…)

Answer (score 5):

I once found out the hard way that /dev/null doesn't *have* to be a special dev file.  A long time ago the /dev/null on an Ultrix system at work got deleted, so the next time a program redirected to /dev/null, it ended up being a normal file full of the output from that program. (I think it was 'no such file or directory', which meant when we were trying to figure out what was going on, we'd do `cat /dev/null` and be told `no such file or directory` which confused the hell out of us.)

So my suggestion would to be replace it with a named pipe, and then attach a program to the pipe that would read it and monitor it.

Comment: A lot of programs also rely in `/dev/null` always returning 0 bytes on a read (`cat /dev/null > foo`).  Having `/dev/null` be a regular file with contents, would break this expectation.

Comment: Yes, that's how we discovered it.  Programs were expecting no input and getting gobs of it, plus /dev/ was getting filled up.

Answer (score 1):

I think of an idea where /dev/null can be a symlink to a file descriptor but with add code mechanism  to determine the operation is read or write and then if it is read, it should actually read from /dev/actualnull created seperately with mknod and if it is write then make a note of the invoking program and attempt to log/count for analyzing the programs that use /dev/null for writing. This is going to cost a lot in terms of performance, I suppose though. I guess it is not practical since most shell programs or code use redirection anyway. May be inotify could be used to monitor the usage of /dev/null ? or rewrite the kernel code that handles 1:3 devices, again compile and reinstall, experimentable.

Comment: There are still some problems, I tried doing something like this (not in-kernel, but transparently-ish by allowing to read from another file and controlling `/dev/null` from a daemon), and `sshd` still complained and wouldn't start.

Comment: hmm..interesting on /dev/null controlling from a daemon. I think most programs just would want to use /dev/null as just another file leaving the importance and semantics of /dev/null to the system.

Comment: Well, `sshd` (at least, as packaged for Debian Squeeze) complains with `sshd: cannot create /dev/null` if it's anything but the most common implementation.