# Read what is written to /dev/tty*

Tags: linux, console, tty

How can I read what is written to `/dev/tty*`(`*` = `0` - number of *tty*)?

I tried `sudo tail -f /dev/tty1` on one terminal(`X`) and then `sudo cp .emacs /dev/tty1` from another. `X` didn't show the the content of `.emacs`but pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-F1</kbd> I could see the content of the `.emacs`.

[Background.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435308/what-is-dev-tty-in-unix)

Is this question of the same category as [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31958/monitor-what-is-being-sent-to-dev-null)?

Answer (score 14):

On Linux, you can dump the current text that is displayed on a text mode console through the [vcs](http://linux.die.net/man/4/vcs) devices. For example, `cat /dev/vcs1` dumps the content of `/dev/tty1`. The vcsa devices (e.g. `/dev/vcsa1`) contain text attributes as well.

Every time you open `/dev/vcsNUM`, you get the current content of the terminal's display buffer. This isn't an interface to what is currently being printed to the terminal — there's no such interface.

For pseudo-terminals, what is currently displayed is tracked by the terminal emulator, and there is no way to dump it unless the terminal emulator provides one. For example, for a pseudo-terminal provided by ssh, the terminal content would be on the client machine.

Comment: These surely are some abstruse ideas to come to terms with. Isn't part of what is being printed become a part of the display buffer?