# Do the standard streams all operate on the same file (/dev/tty)?

Tags: linux

If I type ls -l /dev in a virtual terminal I get

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          15 apr 10 10:59 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          15 apr 10 10:59 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root          15 apr 10 10:59 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
```

If i then type ls -l /proc/self/fd I get

```
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 apr 10 19:59 0 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 apr 10 19:59 1 -> /dev/pts/1
lrwx------ 1 user user 64 apr 10 19:59 2 -> /dev/pts/1
```

All entries point to the same device file, which also happen to be the controlling terminal for the virtual shell (as confirmed by the "tty" command). Am I then right to assume that the stdin, sdout and stderr file descriptors all operate on the same file (/dev/pts/1), e.g. three separate open() calls have been made (when the virtual shell process was forked from its parent process) on the same file?

If so, while running the following program:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int rfd = open("./a_file",O_RDONLY);
    int wfd = open("./a_file",O_WRONLY);

    char rc='a',wc='b';

    if (write(rfd,&wc,1)<0) {
        perror("Error");
    }

    if (read(wfd,&rc,1)<0) {
        perror("Error");
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
Error: Bad file descriptor
Error: Bad file descriptor
```

As expected, but when changing rfd to 1 (sdtout) and wfd to 0 (stdin) in the read() arguments, I don't get an error. Does this mean that /dev/tty was opened with the O_RDWR flag?

When trying:

```
if (write(1,&wc,1)<0) {
    perror("Error");
}

if (read(0,&rc,1)<0) {
    perror("Error");
}
```

I see the 'b' on the console, but the read() call doesn't return, as if there wasn't any data to be read from the file. Why is that?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Agreeing that they all reference the same device, the actual question appears at the very end.  The reason why the `read` fails to return anything is that `/dev/tty` is not just a connection from its *input* to its *output*, but is a connection between your (shell) process and a real device, i.e., the Linux console.  You could have a program running on the console which reads data from the host (such as your example above) and replies (providing data for the `read` call), but without that additional connection, the `read` will have no data.

Further reading:

- [Read what is written to /dev/tty*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/95878/read-what-is-written-to-dev-tty)
- [What is stored in /dev/pts files and can we open them?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93531/what-is-stored-in-dev-pts-files-and-can-we-open-them/93640#93640)
- [How to read/write to tty* device?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device/138390#138390), not a duplicate, 
  but makes the same observation about lack of data to read without explaining.

Comment: But isn't /dev/tty a file in some sense? Using another file than /dev/tty i can open two different fd's, one for writing and one for reading, then write a byte to the file, which i can then read from the read fd. Why is that not possible using /dev/tty? Keep in mind that my two fd do not share the same offset in the kernel. One reason that it would not work on /dev/tty, i can imagine, is that stdin and stdout have the same offset, e.g. have been created with dup()

Comment: A *device* is different from a *file*, because a *device* does something (or can react), while a *file* is passive.  Files hold data, while devices manipulate data.